# How was it concluded by five users that "This question is not about mathematics"?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons

[On the exactness of the calculus formulas](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1689220/on-the-exactness-of-the-calculus-formulas)

Can someone explain how it was concluded by five users that "This question is not about mathematics"?

Comment: Without making a judgement as to whether the close reason is appropriate or not, the close reason is "This question is not about mathematics, **within the scope defined in the help center**." (emphasis added by me).

Comment: @DanielFischer : "Understanding mathematical concepts and theorems." is one of the kinds of questions said to be welcomed.  This question fits very well into that. $\qquad$

Comment: The way this question has been treated is the worst case of irrational hostility to newbies that can be imagined. $\qquad$

Comment: Can the person who down-voted this explain why?  Is it inappropriate to ask about this here?

Comment: It may be that this is displayed as the actual reasons were very diverse. @DanielFischer can you confirm that this reason was actually chosen be the voters to close. (I do not want to assign too much weight to close-reason choosing, but I'd have to say this one would be a peculiar choice 'lack of context', "too broad", "unclear" okay but "not about math" looks odd.)

Comment: @quid : You are right that one should not assign to much weight to reasons to close that are chosen from a short multiple-choice menu.  In recent hours I was told emphatically here one meta that one should not ask why a question was closed because it is always explained via that menu.  I'm glad to see you bringing some common sense to that question. $\qquad$

Comment: Some of the downvotes may be coming from the fact that you made four meta posts about this question since yesterday. Some people may get tired of it. (And it seems from your previous comment that you're continuing your habit of putting words in others' mouths.)

Comment: @quid That's the reason chosen. And I agree that that reason doesn't seem to apply. Not having been exposed to calculus, I still can't understand the point of such a question, but it seems to be in scope. I've reopened it.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi : I wasn't putting words in anyone's mouth.  "T.Bongers" did indeed write that one need never inquire about the reason for closure because it's always indicated by the choice from the short multiple-choice menu.  As "quid" has indicated, that may often fail.

Comment: Please link the comment where T. Bongers said that. (Are you sure you know who's bullying who right now?)

Comment: @NajibIdrissi : It's one of the early comments here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/22780/notifications-to-those-who-vote-to-close $\qquad$

Comment: Which one? I cannot find one where T. Bongers says "that one need never inquire about the reason for closure because it's always indicated by the choice from the short multiple-choice menu".

Comment: @NajibIdrissi : Here is a verbatim quote: "The rationale for closing is always listed in the box for the closure". $\qquad$

Comment: The comment does say that, yes. Where does it say that "one need never inquire about the reason for closure"?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi : Read it in the context in which it is written.  That's what he's saying.  I never said anything was a verbatim quote except the part I said is a verbatim quote. $\qquad$

Comment: Ah, finally. Thanks for finally admitting that this is only your interpretation of what's written.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi : Maybe anything that's not verbatim is an "interpretation".  But "quid" was right when he said one should not infer too much from the rationale chosen from the menu, and that is precisely "T.Bongers" 's mistake in this instance. $\qquad$

Comment: @DanielFischer, is the displayed close reason on a question (one of) the one with the most votes?

Comment: @zyx Yes (and latter vote breaks ties and there may be a fall back if all are different, which was the reason for my question). Note the close message is only "signed" by those that actually closed it with this reason then. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1694242/how-can-i-solve-this-partial-derivative and note that Ron Gordon's name is missing in the list *below the reason.*

Comment: Useful information, and thanks for the edit on the MSE question.  @quid

Comment: Why was this question down-voted? Nobody expresses disagreement with its factual content.  It was just a question, but perhaps with a tacit suggestion that it was wrong to say "This question is not about mathematics", and that suggestion did not remain tacit.  And nobody verbally expressed disagreement with that.  $\qquad$

Comment: This and the corresponding MSE question seem like reasonable questions to me.

Comment: *Why was this question down-voted?* Some of the downvotes may be coming from the fact that you made six meta posts about this question since Friday. Some people may get tired of it.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi : I'm tired of it myself, but this needs to be done.  There are many here from whom I haven't seen much in the way of expressions of gratitude to me for pursuing the matter.

Comment: Aside from that people might get tired of your posts, I did downvote this one as the question as stated ask question that is unanswerable from the community. If your question is really as stated, go ask that five users instead of asking on meta. If not, state your question clearly. @MichaelHardy (I do agree that the linked question is about math though)

Comment: @JohnMa : How can I ask the five users?  Is there some way to contact them?

Comment: @MichaelHardy : Find the comment/question/answers left by that five users on MSE. Leave a message there and invite them to talk to you in chat.

Comment: @MichaelHardy (Sorry, I had removed my comment to edit it before you responded, so it looks out of order now.)  And many users have contact information that they leave in their profiles, including several of the users that Michael Hardy would like to contact. (And having been a user here for just shy of five years, I'm rather surprised that the asker wasn't aware of these methods).

Comment: @JohnMa I do not consider this is a good practice (especially if it is for more than one person). It is a work-around I used at times, and that got used on me so to say. But especially in situations of conflict it can be risky. There are cases on the network were users got banned over doing this.

Comment: @T.Bongers I'd advise strongly against contacting users off-site over such things,  without explicit prior permission on site. There are several instances known to me where this was not appreciated and at least one were it turned quite sour.

Comment: To conclude the above. It is interesting that the dedicate way to contact users on site, though not always possible, was not mentioned so far: namely to invite them to a chat room *using the respective feature of chat.* (Likely I would also not use it in this case though. But it'd be at least a correct on--site way to contact users.)

Comment: Just my 2 cents, but the linked question seems like a good and earnest question. I share your outrage that it was closed.

Comment: @quid: I agree, this practice could be used unless it's really necessary and in a polite way. One should also be aware the other side are completely fine to ignore the request (In case it is not obvious).

Comment: @NajibIdrissi : You wrote: "Some of the downvotes may be coming from the fact that you made four meta posts about this question since yesterday. Some people may get tired of it."  Could we note in the interest of honesty that this question is about something that was not and could not have been addressed in those earlier postings because it hadn't happened yet? The deletion of this question on the pretext that it is not about mathematics (as defined, etc.) had not happened at the time of those earlier postings. $\qquad$

Answer (score 1):

Quid's edit seemed to have disposed of the usual "close reasons", if they were valid for the first closing.   But the question was closed a second time after that.

I would like to say that this was a strange and unique occurrence, but in fact it is common behavior on MSE.

Anyway, thanks to @quid for taking the initiative to forestall the closing of a question that is interesting in itself and has led to several thoughtful answers.